# Plugins to make PHP coding easier and efficient in (g)Vim?

Tags: php, vim

Plugins to make PHP coding easier and efficient in (g)Vim?

e.g. Error detection/highlight, debugging, etc?

Comment: "Error correction" --- pack up this one for me, please.

Comment: @zerkms I didn't get it~

Comment: @alexchenco: it was a joke addressed to the fact that there is no pixie dust and each developer should fix errors manually.

Comment: Simple syntax error detection is certainly possible. But doesn't vim already have syntax highlighting? (This is were I would surmise such an feature.)

Comment: Also a PHP xdebug client for vim exists already: http://tech.blog.box.net/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/

Comment: @zerkms It was a good joke after all. Sorry what I meant was error highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For error detection, there is no miracle, but [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Syntastic) is a good start.

If you have installed xdebug, then you can use :

- [DBGp-client](http://github.com/vim-scripts/DBGp-client)
- [vim-add-xdebug](http://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-addon-xdebug) (I never used it, but seems more recent)
- [DBGPavim](https://github.com/brookhong/DBGPavim) (the most recent, nice plugin with good documentation)

Also, there is a package with some PHP config/plugins all-in-one, [PIV](http://github.com/vim-scripts/PIV), but I prefer installing plugins one by one.

Finally, the best advice would be to **first** install [Vundle](http://github.com/vim-scripts/vundle), so that you can then do this :

```
:BundleSearch php
```

Then yank the plugins results you're interested in, into your `.vimrc`, then

```
:BundleInstall
```

And you can test these plugins in no time. And launch `:BundleClean` after removing lines in your `.vimrc` if you don't like the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found the free book 'A Byte of Vim' very helpful.  It contains descriptions of a useful set of plugins.

http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim

See also Dr Chip's Vim page.

http://www.drchip.org/